# How to change font-weight based on a condition and then change color based on a different condition without overriding? (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
      if (Math.abs(decimalChange) > .025){ //bold significant changes
        tdChange.style = 'font-weight:bold;';
      }

      if (decimalChange >= 0){
        tdChange.style = 'color:green;';
      }
      else {
        tdChange.style = 'color:red;';
      }
```

Above there are 2 conditions that determine two separate properties of a TD element tdChange based on the contents of a number decimalChange.  I am finding that whichever of the 2 conditions I put last works as desired, while the one that comes first is ignored.  I can easily presume that I am overwriting one with the other, however when I try substituting the right side of the equation of the second property to be updated with

```
tdChange.style + 'theSecondPropertyIAmAdjusting';
```

I find that neither property is implemented.  How can I go about determining the font weight of an element based on one condition and then subsequently determining the font color of that same element based on a different condition without overriding the results of the first property implemented?

Comment: By not using `.style` at all for this, but CSS classes instead. Don't define your styling in code unless you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

Several options. One possibility is using `object.style.property` syntax. This way you can define multiple properties.

The way you were declaring it, the properties would always get overridden.

```js
var tdChange = document.getElementById('tdChange');

var numbers = [.03, .18, -.018];
var randNumber = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
if (Math.abs(randNumber) > .025){ //bold significant changes
    tdChange.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}

tdChange.style.color = randNumber >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red';
```

```html
<p id='tdChange'>This is a paragraph</p>
```

You could also use the `toggleClass` method in jQuery. This will check whether an element has a class. If it doesn't it will add the class, if not it will remove it.

```js
var tdChange = $('#tdChange');
var numbers = [.03, .18, -.018];
var randNumber = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];

if (Math.abs(randNumber) > .025) {
    tdChange.toggleClass('bold');
}

tdChange.toggleClass(randNumber >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red');
```

```css
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.green { color: green; }
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='tdChange'>This is a paragraph</p>
```